# Notification of core data changes after loading an SQL file

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsdocument

Is there a way to be notified that a previously saved core data document has been loaded?

Comment: Core Data persistent stores only get loaded on demand. They're loaded when you load them. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have an `NSTableView` that is filled using core data. I also have an `NSPredicateEditor` that needs to be refreshed after loading a document. I need to know when I need to do that, and one of those moments is after I load a saved document (XML, binary or SQL).